# Cannot run "Automation Anywhere" exe files from console (session 0) on Windows Server 2003 64 bit

Tags: automation, console, executable, session

I have a simple exe created from an [Automation Anywhere](http://www.automationanywhere.com/) task that displays a message box saying hello world. I created this simple exe just for debugging the following issue.

When I log in to the console (session 0), and run the Automation Anywhere created executable, it starts to run the task, it shows up in the applications and processes list in the task manager and it shows the two "loading..." windows briefly on the screen, just like normal.

But after that, nothing happens... the "hello world" message does not show up. The exe is done and is removed from the application and process list in the task manager.

The user I am logged in as, has admin rights and the machine uses "autologin" to automatically log in using this profile when it starts up.

If I right click on the exe and "run as" another admin user, the exe runs properly, showing the "hello world" message.

Also, if I log into the server in a new session, with the original user (the one that has the problems in session 0), and then run the exe, it runs properly and shows the "hello world". It works fine in any session other than the console session.

There is something about the console session that is causing the exe not to run properly... even though it does appear to start running the exe.

I should also mention that everything was working fine until Monday at midnight, after which none of the executables could be run successfully. Nothing was changed on the server and no updates were installed. I have since installed windows updates, but that didn't change anything.

Looking for some advice on how to get these executables working in the console session again.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the event logs? Joel

Comment: #1: Windows cannot unload your classes registry file - it is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded when it is no longer in use. 

(then 3 seconds later...)

#2: Windows saved user MAXIMPOWERCORP\corpdev registry while an application or service was still using the registry during log off. The memory used by the user's registry has not been freed. The registry will be unloaded when it is no longer in use. 

 This is often caused by services running as a user account, try configuring the services to run in either the LocalService or NetworkService account.

Comment: Those only appeared once a few days before my issue started... and I believe it was at the time of an automatic restart I have set on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can help if the process is hanging on while trying to do something external to the .exe.  It probably won't help if there is something wrong/corrupt with the .exe.

See if there are any options to run the .exe w/ debug/logging output, or if the .exe can be recompiled with logging options.